# Textblob language translation

Tags: python, automation, textblob

```
from textblob import TextBlob

trans = TextBlob("text")

translated_text = trans.translate(to='en')

print("Translated text:", translated_text)
```

While running this code, I'm getting error like this:

```
translated_text = trans.translate(from_lang="ml",to='en')
AttributeError: 'TextBlob' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.